# strcmp() is not working in php

Tags: php, strcmp

I use the strcmp() to compare two strings in php, code below:

```
$tagname = "td";
$acq_data = extracting_data_tagname($url, $tagname); 

$dir = $acq_data[205];  
echo "this is $dir";
echo strcmp($dir, "NW");
```

The Result print:
this is NW
-1

Why the strcmp($dir, "NW") =-1, it should be =0, Anyone can tell me what's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: your `$dir` as no value

Comment: $dir no value? what do you mean? in my code the $dir is taking 205th <td> element from a web page.

Comment: Are you sure the $acq_data has an index no. 205. Also throw some light on function extracting_data_tagname($url, $tagname); and also the echo statement should be "echo "this is ".$dir "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think that `$dir` has `NW` value you should try with `trim()` function:

```
echo strcmp(trim($dir), "NW");
```

If it will return 0, it means that you have some whitespaces at the beginning or at the end of `$dir` variable.

Answer (score 2):

> this is NW -1

There appears to be a space in there, which would mean that `$dir` is `"NW "`, which is not equal to `"NW"`.

You should use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) when debugging things like this.  It gives output that's more helpful and clear, to both us and you.